# GTK and Qt - what are they?

Tags: 14.04, gtk, qt

Fairly new to Ubuntu, but having some issues with Lazarus and FPC programming.

In the Lazarus IDE I keep finding things that do not work and the Lazarus Forum keep telling me that those functions work in Qt but not in GTK.

OK, I can live with changing, so how do I change from GTK (I think that is what I have in the standard 14.04) to Qt?

I have spent most of yesterday trying things I have found online and nothing so far completes, eventually doing nothing, or crashing with a variety of errors. Ranging from no login page to no booting. I have an Image back I keep restoring and thats getting tedious.

I first followed the "Ubuntu Official Documentation" instructions and on reboot, that got the equivalent of the windows BSOD, so I had to Restore. Then I began searching and trying things that sounded the person might know what they were writing about.

After something like six Restores I am here asking for help with something that is for the current and up-to-date 14.04 that will work.

Comment: I'm not a programmer, just some bash scripting and python stuff. In simple terms GTK and QT are toolkits, the thing that provides you with buttons, sliders, text boxes etc and the routines that go with them. Gnome uses GTK (Gnome tool kit) and KDE uses QT, but GTK and QT are desktop agnostic so you can install the libraries for any tool kit onto any desktop and design and run applications using any of the toolkits.

Comment: I think you need Kubuntu 14.04. Kubuntu is based on KDE which is based on QT.

Comment: @theGtknerd: Thanks, are you saying I have to scrap my current 14.04 setup and install Kubuntu? Seems like an awful lot of work. If I understand hatterman, he/she seems to suggest I can just install it in place of or alongside GTK. But as I stated above I have yet to find any instructions on that actually work.

Comment: @hatterman: Thanks for the explanation, do you have any suggestions on where to find instructions to install QT that really work? Is there a main "QT" site? I found Qt, Qt, Qt4, QT5.6 mostly different sites and no idea which or what I need. Very confusing for newbies to Linux.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what feature (of Lazarus) that doesn't work for you, but I am guessing this feature only works if you have a window manager that uses QT. Kubuntu is the easiest way to get a QT window manager. You could install a window manager like KDE on your normal Ubuntu 14.04 but get ready for quite a bit of work. By the way, there are easier ways to program on Linux than Lazarus. Python and Java are both well known for documentation and GUI toolkits.

Comment: You don't have to scrap anything. Run `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` and you'll get everything Kubuntu has

Comment: I dont know if you need all or just some of the qt framework. I think what usually happens is that you either subscribe to the qt infrastructure or the gtk infrastructure., and this dictates the desktop environment you will use. For example gnome for gtk and kde for qt. I use a gnome based desktop, so i predominantly use gtk applications, but i can install kde applications withiut issue, i just have to be prepared for a large amount of kde stuff to also be installed to provide dependencies. Why dont you install synaptic package manager (sudo apt-get install synaptic) and do a search for qt. Yo